# Edit content with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I try to edit comments in my blog with AJAX.
But i get error on my edit method on controller.
`ActionController::UnknownFormat in CommentsController#edit`

```rb
def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.author.comments.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
          format.js {render 'edit', status: :created, location: @post}
        end
      end
    end
```

**UPD**

I added string:

```rb
...
   respond_to do |format|
          format.js {render 'edit', status: :created, location: @post}
          format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'You voted' }
                   ^^^this string
...
```

And and the error is gone.
But javascript is not executing and the page just reloads

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? There is also no way that we will be able to help you without knowing how you sent the request and the rails log which shows what request was received. There is nothing in the question which tells us anything about the why this failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you are submitting form as Js request.

in this case, I think Your form is submitting, but it's not sending as a JS request. so your edit action crashes looking for an HTML response.

What you need is to add remote: true to your edit link so that will render and execute the edit.js.erb file. Or if you are making ajax call then add dataType attribute with value 'script' .

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'script',
  method: 'GET',
  data: { id: id, post_id: post_id },
  url: URL_FOR_EDIT
});
```